# como, convertir mis filas en columnas agrupadas, en sql server 2008 MySQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

[image: CONSULTA GENERAL]

Hola, al ejecutar esa consulta obtengo el siguiente resultado, pero lo que a mi me gustaría o mas bien busco, es que por cada puesto se cree una columna y en esa columna estén los empleados que son de ese puesto. He probado con cursores pero eso lo hace mas tardado pues me gustaría que fuera dinámico

[image: RESULTADO ESPERADO]

añado una imagen del ejemplo que me gustaria que quede mi consulta como resultado, espero puedan ayudarme.

Comment: podrías llegar a obtener algo similar con un CASE WHEN  harcodeando las columnas, pero no te quedaría como lo necesitas en la imagen de ejemplo.   Con sqlserver tienen un lenguage de procedimientos llamado t-sql que no lo conozco bien, pero en el caso de un oracle o postgresql con sus lenguajes de procedimientos si podrías resolver esta situación.

Comment: Es posible pero bastante complejo. Sin un [mcve] es muy complicado responderte. Hay varias respuesta en el sitio que pueden ayudarte, la clave a buscar es PIVOT, aunque también puede resolverse sin usar esta clausula, pero no existe ningún dinamismo, tienes que establecer de antemano cuales van a ser la las columnas. Además, horizontalmente siempre vas a tener un límite máximo de columnas